# How can I delete everything except a specific function in ruby using vim?

Tags: vim

I have this following buffer:

```
class Greeting
  def english_greeting
    words.each do
      # do some stuff
    end
    return 'hello'
  end

  def spanish_greeting
    # do some stuff
    return 'hola'
  end
end
```

I want a way of deleting everything except english_greeting function and its content. I do realize that I can use `matchit.vim` and jump to `def spanish_greeting` yank that function and then delete everything then print the yanked buffer. But I was wondering if there is any other way to deal with that?

Comment: In this situation you really will be best off with something that can actually recognize ruby methods. I would check out vim-ruby: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting unwanted lines, you can collect wanted lines:

```
:g/^def english_/,/^end/y A
```

All `english` related functions go into register `"a`, you can put it out with <kbd>"ap</kbd>.

Comment: That would not work if I have a do-end block inside the function. This method will match the `end` that is inside the function.

Comment: `/^end/` only matches beginning of line.

Comment: You are right. Maybe the example I had was oversimplified. `end` will not be matched  if it were a method in a class.

Answer (score 0):

One - not so elegant - way could be do this.

```
ggd/def english_greeting<Enter>
```

This will delete everything before the `english_greeting` function.

Now, to delete all remainig functions (after `english_greeting` function),

```
/def<Enter>dG
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
:0;/^def english_greeting$/-1 d | /^end$/+1,$ d
```

It assumes that `def` and `end` are not preceded by any white space.
The reason for this is that otherwise if you have a `do`, `end` block or an `if` statement inside `english_greeting` it will delete from that `end`, and delete too much.
This way, if you use code indenting, you should end up with the whole method.
If you don't want the command to ask for confirmation before executing, just add `silent`, i.e. `:silent 0;...`.

Another option is to install the [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) plugin.
It adds a text object for ruby methods, so you could easily yank the whole method to a named buffer. To use buffer `a`, for example, you would place the cursor anywhere in the method and type `"ayam`. Then you can just delete all the text in the file, say with `ggdG`, and paste the method back in with `"ap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this substitute command:

```
:%s/\_.*\(def english_greeting\_.*\)def\_.*/\1/
```